# How can I enter Null/None into mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am using Python 3.7 and pyMySQL  as a connector to MySQL server.

I am trying to do the following query:

```
query="INSERT IGNORE INTO  tweets (ID, Text,create," \
                    "Date,local,foolowed,Count," \
                    "isqwdii,inR,in " \
                    "Sensitive,redirection)" \
                    "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%d,%d)"
vals=[kwargs['ID'], kwargs['Text'],
                   kwargs['create'], kwargs['Date'],
                   kwargs['local'], kwargs['foolowed'],
                   kwargs['Count'], kwargs['isascii'],
                   kwargs['inR'], kwargs['in'],
                   kwargs['Sensitive'], kwargs['redirection']] 
self.__cur.execute(query,vals)
self.__conn.commit()
```

the problem is that some of the %d can be None and when it happens I get the following error "TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str".

I can't use the format because it will make get None as string in the DB. I want the DB get it as None/NULL

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right! thank you. I knew that it's string type , the problem that I though that I can get decimal with placeholder s (I am trying to retrieve info from a website and some of the fields can be none and can be decimal)

Comment: Yes, as I said, you will need to adjust the `%s`/ `%d` type definition *IN PYTHON* when assesssing if the value given is a `null` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to test if it is `NULL` in your Python code and if so, replace the `%d` with `%s` for *string*.

(*My experience in PHP is Null is a string type and so I am assuming this is carried across to the Python MySQL interfaces*)

therefore pseudo-code would be:

```
>>>    type['isascii'] = '%d'
>>>    if kwargs['isascii'] is None:
>>>        type['isascii'] = '%s'

>>>>   query= "INSERT IGNORE INTO  tweets (ID, Text,create," \
                "Date,local,foolowed,Count," \
                "isqwdii,inR,in " \
                "Sensitive,redirection)" \
                f"VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d,{str(type['isascii'])},%s,%s,%d,%d)"
```

I apologise because I do not know Python 3.7 syntax, but I hope this gives you the concept.

Response from Leo120:

> Actually it worked when I placed all placeholders as %s (and got all the data as needed in the MySQL). as it turns out, in the pymysql %s stands for all, wierd. thank you for your help

Comment: You are right! thank you. I knew that it's string type , the problem that I though that I can not  get decimal with placeholder s (I am trying to retrieve info from a website and some of the fields can be none and can be decimal)

Comment: @Leo120 decimal has a placeholder `%d` for *double*. You will need to dynamically set the type value before executing the query, depending on if it is a `null` (`string`) or not (`double`/`int`/`blob`)

Comment: Actually it worked when i placed all placeholders as %s (and got all the data as needed in the MySQL). as it turns out, in the pymysql %s stands for all, wierd. thank you for your help

Comment: @Leo120 thanks for letting me know! I will add you comment to my answer for clarity.